# "Archive mode" - Implementing a data freeze

Tags: database, migration, maintenance

I am planning on doing some awfully heavy-handed updates to an old 1.4 store that is in production. The site is not really used for selling anything, but mostly used as an information library for each "product" being sold at a brick and mortar. There are Gift Cards being sold, but these are uncommon and they only sell once every handful of days or so, if this stopped working for a few days, it's not a big deal.

I would like to implement a data freeze on the site so that the database gets frozen for (most likely) a day or two while I migrate content/entities/etc over to another server instance. Putting the store in maintenance mode is not desirable, as I still want customers to be able to browse the site/product pages/etc, but I don't want anyone changing records during migration.

While I suspect some hard-editing of `index.php` will be in order, I'd prefer to not have to edit any application files, and would rather freeze things at a server level.

**With this in mind, what are some effective strategies for implementing a data freeze necessary for migrating entities?**

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just disable customer's registration and payment methods?

To disable customer registration you can use a module like this:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/medma-disable-customer-registration.html

You could also disable login by editing the customer constroller or adding an observer.

**Anyway, the BEST option is to make a copy and work on it on another server.**

Comment: I may be wrong but regarding customer registration disable I think turning disable module output to Yes for Mage_Customer would do it

Comment: Excellent idea. Do it from backend, because backend disable just turn off the module's output. Do not do from app/etc/modules or you will break your Magento.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but the main concern is updates by employees during migration. What I will probably end up doing is just telling people, "don't make any site changes", as I am essentially going to be unifying multiple data entry points (old point of sale system and related tools for updating product info) into a single API that I will be moving outside of Magento. "Single source of truth" means that at some point I need to shut off old data storage points, one of which is Magento.